# Can't bind ItemsControl.ItemTemplate to List<object> element

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, binding, itemscontrol

I'm in trouble. I created UserControl that looks below:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITxkS.jpg

I have dependency property "Text" bound to TextBlock.Text of the UserControl. I want to create another UserControl that visualize List. Here is my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListPresenter.ListViewer"
         xmlns:dop="clr-namespace:DeletableObjectPresenter;assembly=DeletableObjectPresenter"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding List, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <ItemContainerTemplate>
                  <dop:DeletableObjectPresenter></dop:DeletableObjectPresenter>
              </ItemContainerTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ListPresenter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ListViewer.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ListViewer : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ListProperty =                     DependencyProperty.Register(
        "List", typeof (IList<object>), typeof (ListViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public List<object> List 
        {
            get { return (List<object>) GetValue(ListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ListProperty, value); }
        }
        public ListViewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is look of my control:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIjHy.jpg

The problem is that i don't know how to bind Text of the Item to list's element. Thank you!

Comment: Replace ItemContainerTemplate with DataTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to create a [`DependencyProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) for your `Text` property in your `UserControl`. You should data bind to this property in your `UserControl`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type dop:DeletableObjectPresenter}}}" />
```

Now you can data bind to the `Text` property of your `UserControl` from the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <dop:DeletableObjectPresenter Text="{Binding PropertyToBindToText}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Of course, your objects in your `List` collection will need to have a property (named `PropertyToBindToText` in this example) to data bind to the `Text` property of your `UserControl`. As such, you'd be better off creating a strongly typed collection instead of your `List<object>` and furthermore, it is customary to use `ObservableCollection<T>` in WPF.

See the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information.